# Are SOAP web services are getting deprecated from sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am new to sharepoint development and I have seen this from MSDN site.

> Two API sets are still supported in the SharePoint 2013 framework for
>   backward compatibility, but we recommend that you not use them for new
>   projects: the ASP.NET (asmx) web services, and direct Remote Procedure
>   Calls (RPC) calls to the owssvr.dll file.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx#DeprecatedAPIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP is officially on the deprecated list, but I was talking to a MVP familiar with these SOAP services. He does not see them going away any time soon, there is still too much under the hood that uses these services.

I would say if there is an alternative end point through REST, try to use that, but don't be afraid of using the SOAP services so long as you understand they are deprecated and could be removed at any point. This means you'd need to refactor at some point.

Other people on the boards here are in the other camp saying if it's deprecated, move away from it immediately. Do what works best for you in your current scenario.